# asp gridview scrolling keeps jumping to top

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try thousands of code posted on Internet. There is no error, but it still not works. When I edit or update in gridview, it just keep jumping to the top. (the vertical scroll bar auto scrolls to the first record.) Please help. Thanks!

below is my code:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="StaceyCost.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.StaceyCost"  MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
   div.scroll {
         width: 1850px;
         height: 630px;
         overflow: scroll;

        }


    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(/images/bg4.jpg)">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
      <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>&nbsp;Project Cost</h1>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Client:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>AAH</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ALLY</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>AMREF</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>CAP</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>CSS</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ICSF</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>IPPF</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>JTS</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>NUL</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>NYRP</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>PFTH</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>QLF</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>SJS</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>TCS</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>WPHC</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>VAC</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </p>
         <table width="1850" border="0">
             <tr>
             <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:center">

     <input type="hidden" id="hdnScrollTop" runat="server" value="0" />
                  <div class="scroll">
                 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Project_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-Width ="80px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Linkbutton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:Linkbutton>
                                 &nbsp;<asp:Linkbutton ID="Linkbutton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:Linkbutton>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:Button>
                             </ItemTemplate>

<HeaderStyle Width="80px"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Number" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Project_ID">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Project_ID") %>' Width ="80px" ></asp:Label>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Project_ID") %>' Width ="80px" ></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campaign Name" SortExpression="Campaign_Name">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Campaign_Name") %>' Width ="400px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Campaign_Name") %>' Width ="400px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertCampaign_Name" runat="server" Width ="400px"  ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Drop Date" SortExpression="Drop_Date">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Drop_Date", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' TextMode="Date" Width ="130px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Drop_Date","{0:d}") %>' Width ="130px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertDropDate" runat="server" Width ="130px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="House Qty" SortExpression="House_Qty">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("House_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("House_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertHouse_Qty" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="House Cost" SortExpression="House_Cost">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("House_Cost" )%>' Width ="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("House_Cost", "{0:c2}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertHouse_Cost" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acq Qty" SortExpression="Acq_Qty">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Acq_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Acq_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertAcq_Qty" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acq Cost" SortExpression="Acq_Cost">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Acq_Cost") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Acq_Cost", "{0:c2}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertAcq_Cost" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="List Cost" SortExpression="List_Cost">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("List_Cost") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("List_Cost", "{0:c2}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertList_Cost" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Cost" SortExpression="Data_Cost">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Data_Cost") %>' Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Data_Cost", "{0:c2}") %>' Width ="80px" ></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertData_Cost" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Qty" SortExpression="Total_Qty">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);"  ></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px" ></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertTotal_Qty" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Cost" SortExpression="Total_Cost">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total_Cost") %>' Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total_Cost", "{0:c2}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertTotal_Cost" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="House CPP" SortExpression="House_CPP">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("House_CPP") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("House_CPP","{0:c2}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertHouse_CPP" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acq CPP" SortExpression="Acq_CPP">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Acq_CPP") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Acq_CPP","{0:c2}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertAcq_CPP" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Team Qty" SortExpression="Datateam_Qty">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Datateam_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Datateam_Qty", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="80px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertDatateam_Qty" runat="server" Width ="80px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty Difference" SortExpression="Qty_Diff">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Qty_Diff", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="60px" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Qty_Diff", "{0:#,0}") %>' Width ="60px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertQty_Diff" runat="server" Width ="60px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note" SortExpression="Note1">
                             <EditItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Note1") %>' Width ="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                             </EditItemTemplate>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Note1") %>' Width ="120px"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertNote1" runat="server" Width ="120px" ></asp:TextBox>
                             </FooterTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                     </Columns>
                     <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Medium" />
                 </asp:GridView>
              </div>
             </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Comma(Num) { //function to add commas to textboxes
        Num += '';
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        x = Num.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1))
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        return x1 + x2;
    }
</script>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:productionConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [project] WHERE [Project_ID] = @Project_ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [project] ([Campaign_Name], [Drop_Date], [House_Qty], [House_Cost], [Acq_Qty], [Acq_Cost], [List_Cost], [Data_Cost], [Total_Qty], [Total_Cost], [House_CPP], [Acq_CPP], [Datateam_Qty], [Qty_Diff], [Note1]) VALUES (@Campaign_Name, @Drop_Date, @House_Qty, @House_Cost, @Acq_Qty, @Acq_Cost, @List_Cost, @Data_Cost, @Total_Qty, @Total_Cost, @House_CPP, @Acq_CPP, @Datateam_Qty, @Qty_Diff, @Note1)" SelectCommand="SELECT [Project_ID], [Campaign_Name], [Drop_Date], [House_Qty], [House_Cost], [Acq_Qty], [Acq_Cost], [List_Cost], [Data_Cost], [Total_Qty], [Total_Cost], [House_CPP], [Acq_CPP], [Datateam_Qty], [Qty_Diff], [Note1] FROM [project] WHERE (([Client] = @Client) AND ([Complete] = @Complete)) ORDER BY [Project_ID] DESC" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [project] SET [Campaign_Name] = @Campaign_Name, [Drop_Date] = @Drop_Date, [House_Qty] = @House_Qty, [House_Cost] = @House_Cost, [Acq_Qty] = @Acq_Qty, [Acq_Cost] = @Acq_Cost, [List_Cost] = @List_Cost, [Data_Cost] = @Data_Cost, [Total_Qty] = @Total_Qty, [Total_Cost] = @Total_Cost, [House_CPP] = @House_CPP, [Acq_CPP] = @Acq_CPP, [Datateam_Qty] = @Datateam_Qty, [Qty_Diff] = @Qty_Diff, [Note1] = @Note1 WHERE [Project_ID] = @Project_ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Project_ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Campaign_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Drop_Date" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="House_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="House_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Acq_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Acq_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="List_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Data_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Total_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Total_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="House_CPP" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Acq_CPP" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Datateam_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Qty_Diff" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Note1" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Client" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="true" Name="Complete" Type="Boolean" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Campaign_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Drop_Date" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="House_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="House_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Acq_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Acq_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="List_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Data_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Total_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Total_Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="House_CPP" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Acq_CPP" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Datateam_Qty" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Qty_Diff" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Note1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Project_ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I try thousands of code posted on Internet. But it still not working. When I edit or update in gridview, it just keep jumping to the top. (the vertical scroll bar auto scrolls to the first record.) Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the vertical scroll bar auto scrolls to the first record?

Comment: @MikeG  yes, that what I mean

Comment: @AngusChung  top of grid view

Answer (score 1):

I assume the page is doing a full postback. If so, set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"` inside your @Page directive. That will keep the page at that position after the postback.

Comment: I add it in the first line you can see. but it still does not work.

Comment: @Xiao the code you posted says `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"`. It should be PostBack instead of Postback, which would result in an error. Did it give you an error? Please be more descriptive than "it doesn't work."

Comment: there's no error. I edit as PostBack. but the gridview still jump to top row.

Comment: Whoops, it is `Postback` when it is in the page directive, and `PostBack` when you're referencing it server side. My mistake. ANyway, if `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` isn't working, then you have to troubleshoot the combination of your .NET Framework version and the version of your browser you're using (or the mode your browser is falling back into). Do you have any .browser files in your application? Sometimes those can interfere. Have you installed Windows Updates? I remember troubleshooting a browser issue with IE 11 where I had to install a hotfix from Microsoft to get it to work.